# Caratheodory solutions of ODEs and sensitivity w.r.t. initial datum

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $T\in\mathbb{R}_{> 0}$ and $f\in L^{\infty}((0,T);W^{1,\infty}(\mathbb{R}))$ be given and consider for $(t_{0},x_{0})\in [0,T]\times\mathbb{R}$ the initial value problem for $t\in[0,T]$
\begin{equation}
z'(t)=f(t,z(t)),\quad \quad z(t_{0})=x_{0}.\tag{IVP} \label{IVP}
\end{equation}
Then, $f$ satisfies the Caratheodory conditions [Wikipedia: Caratheodory's existence Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_existence_theorem) and we obtain a global solution of the \ref{IVP}.
Let us denote this solution by $z_{(t_{0},x_{0})}$ for given initial datum $(t_{0},x_{0})$. Then, the solution satisfies (this is the definition of a Caratheodory solution) the integral equality
$$
z_{(t_{0},x_{0})}(t)=x_{0}+\int_{t_{0}}^{t}f(s,z_{(t_{0},x_{0})}(s))\;\mathrm{d} s. \label{IE}\tag{IE}
$$

Do we have then some stability results regarding the initial datum?
It seems like we have a Lipschitz-continuity, i.e. for $x_{0},x_{1}\in\mathbb{R}$ we have -- using \ref{IE}
$$
z_{(t_{0},x_{0})}(t)-z_{(t_{0},x_{1})}(t)=x_{0}-x_{1}+\int_{t_{0}}^{t}f(s,z_{(t_{0},x_{0})}(s))-f(s,z_{(t_{0},x_{1})}(s))\;\mathrm{d} s.
$$
By the stated regularity assumption of $f$ in the second component, it looks like we can estimate this to obtain
$$
\left|z_{(t_{0},x_{0})}(t)-z_{(t_{0},x_{1})}(t)\right|\leq |x_{0}-x_{1}| +\|\partial_{2}f\|_{L^{\infty}(L^{\infty})}\int_{t_{0}}^{t} \left|z_{(t_{0},x_{0})}(s)-z_{(t_{0},x_{1})}(s)\right|\mathrm{d}s.
$$
Applying Gronwall's Lemma yields the Lipschitz-continuity w.r.t the spatial initial datum. In particular, we have $\tfrac{\partial}{\partial x_{0}} z_{(t_{0},x_{0})}(t)$ exists and is essentially bounded (Rademacher).

**Now my question**: For $f\in C^{1}$ this derivative also satisfies a solution formula -- dependent on the solution $z_{(t_{0},x_{0})}$. Can we have the same in this weaker setting?
Since we now know that the derivative exists a.e., can we perform the following computation: Differentiating both sides in \ref{IE}, we have
$$
\tfrac{\partial}{\partial x_{0}} z_{(t_{0},x_{0})}(t)=1+\int_{t_{0}}^{t}\partial_{2}f(s,z_{(t_{0},x_{0})}(s))\tfrac{\partial}{\partial x_{0}} z_{(t_{0},x_{0})}(s)\,\mathrm{d} s.
$$
Clearly, this is a linear integral equality and we can solve it, but what puzzles me is why the term on the right hand side should even be well-defined. $\partial_{2}f$ is only $L^{\infty}$, thus the composition of $\partial_{2}f$ with $\tfrac{\partial}{\partial x_{0}} z_{(t_{0},x_{0})}$ does not seem to be well defined (measurability).

Is this formula for $\tfrac{\partial}{\partial x_{0}} z_{(t_{0},x_{0})}$ not existent or am I missing a crucial point about measurability and integration?

Thanks in advance to everyone for reading this long question!
Alex

Comment: Perhaps the paper [Weak topologies for Carathéodory differential equations. Continuous dependence, exponential dichotomy and attractors](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jde.2017.08.006) by Longo, Novo and Obaya could be helpful to you (If you don't have access to the JDE web site, you can see the [arXiv version](https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.06343)). Incidentally, in the ODE theory **stability**  connotes the behavior over long intervals of time (e.g. as time goes to infinity), whereas what you're interested in is called (continuous, $C^1$, etc.) **dependence**.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, you are right, I changed the title accordingly. Thanks also for the reference, I will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the standard theory gives answers to your questions. In particular, look at Remark 18.4.16 (et cetera) of [Kurzweil, Ordinary Differential Equations
Introduction to the Theory of Ordinary Differential Equations in the Real Domain](https://www.elsevier.com/books/ordinary-differential-equations/kurzweil/978-0-444-99509-4).